# How to select multiple contacts from the phone using checkboxes

Tags: android, android-contacts

I am trying to select contacts available from the phone programmatically and I am using the below code

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        intent.setType(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

However the question is How can I select multiple contacts at a time by using a checkbox in the contacts page?

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://github.com/1gravity/Android-ContactPicker (I'm the author)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You will have to read the Contacts programmatically and display them in a `ListView` in your `Activity`. Use `CheckBox`s in the `ListView` items and allow multiple items to be selected. Find a simple example/tutorial for a `ListView` and start from there.

There are several reasons why it is better to create a custom `ListView` rather than using `Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);`:

1. There may not be a way to select multiples as you have requested.
2. Even if you find a way to select multiples, it will be different on
   every OS version and device, and might not work on all of them.
3. If there are multiple applications installed on any device that can
   handle `ACTION_GET_CONTENT`, then a chooser will be presented to the
   user and he will have to select one of those. The user's selection
   may not support selecting multiple contacts.

---

Here is an example that reads your system contacts:

```
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,null, null, null, null); 
while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
    String contactId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
    String hasPhone = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER)); 
    String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
    if("1".equals(hasPhone) || Boolean.parseBoolean(hasPhone)) { 
        // You know it has a number so now query it like this
        Cursor phones = myActivity.getContentResolver().query( ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = "+ contactId, null, null); 
        while (phones.moveToNext()) { 
            String phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
            int itype = phones.getInt(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE));

            final boolean isMobile =
                itype == ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MOBILE ||
                itype == ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_WORK_MOBILE;

            // Do something here with 'phoneNumber' such as saving into 
            // the List or Array that will be used in your 'ListView'.

        } 
        phones.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: the answer below is working great without custom listview :) see @Gdroid

Comment: This seems to work only on Samsung devices that have the specific contact app that works with this specific intent. Most of the devices will throw `android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent`

Answer (score 3):

```
   public static final int REQUEST_CODE_PICK_CONTACT = 1;
   public static final int  MAX_PICK_CONTACT= 10;

   private void launchMultiplePhonePicker() {

        Intent phonebookIntent = new Intent("intent.action.INTERACTION_TOPMENU");
        phonebookIntent.putExtra("additional", "phone-multi");
        phonebookIntent.putExtra("maxRecipientCount", MAX_PICK_CONTACT);
        phonebookIntent.putExtra("FromMMS", true);
        startActivityForResult(phonebookIntent, REQUEST_CODE_PICK_CONTACT);

     }



@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if(resultCode==RESULT_OK)
    {

    if(requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_PICK_CONTACT  )
    {

        Bundle bundle =  data.getExtras();

        String result= bundle.getString("result");
        ArrayList<String> contacts = bundle.getStringArrayList("result");


        Log.i(TAG, "launchMultiplePhonePicker bundle.toString()= " + contactsPick.toString() );

        }
    }

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Comment: This seems to work only on Samsung devices that have the specific contact app that works with this specific intent. Most of the devices will throw `android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent `