# How to send specific id to intent picking contacts

Tags: android, android-intent

I can pick multi contact data via

```
   Intent phonebookIntent = new Intent("intent.action.INTERACTION_TOPMENU");
    phonebookIntent.putExtra("additional", "phone-multi");
    phonebookIntent.putExtra("maxRecipientCount", MAX_PICK_CONTACT);
    phonebookIntent.putExtra("FromMMS", true);
    startActivityForResult(phonebookIntent, REQUEST_CODE_PICK_CONTACT);
```

but when I want to add another contact  to present data , the selected contact data  disappears.Is there an intent filter like "selectedList" by which I can send id list  to contact picker intent

Comment: I don't follow. Could you be more elaborate about what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I have a button. when it is clicked, the code above runs and  I can select multi contact. as ex, I have picked 3 datas with contact ids 23,54,67.  I read contact datas with ids 23,54,67 and put what I read into a list. after this, when  I want to add another contact to list and click the button , I see a contact list with no selected ids( 23,54,67). Namely, When  I click the button second time, I want contacts with ids 23,54,67 to be selected

Comment: see this question for code you can use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15620805/how-to-select-multiple-contacts-from-the-phone-using-checkboxes

Answer (score 0):

That could be impossible to do using implicit intent. You can always create your own activity, get the contacts using ContentProvider, pass the parameters you want and handle the logic there.